# Pandas groupby ID between specific date timedelta

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe :

| Birth_Time | ID | Failure_ID | Time_of_failure | COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-05 19:16 | 0 | 0 | 2021-05-05 19:05 | BLUE |
| 2021-05-05 19:16 | 0 | 0 | 2021-05-05 19:12 | BLUE |
| 2021-05-05 19:16 | 0 | 0 | 2021-05-05 19:27 | YELLOW |
| 2021-05-05 19:38 | 1 | 0 | 2021-05-05 19:36 | RED |
| 2021-05-05 19:38 | 1 | 0 | 2021-05-05 19:43 | YELLOW |
| 2021-05-05 19:38 | 1 | 0 | 2021-05-05 19:45 | RED |
| 2021-05-05 19:38 | 1 | 0 | 2021-05-05 19:55 | RED |
| 2021-05-05 20:10 | 2 | 0 | 2021-05-05 20:45 | YELLOW |
| -------- | -- | -- | -------- | -------------- |
| 2021-05-05 22:38 | 11 | 6 | 2021-05-05 22:20 | RED |
| 2021-05-05 22:38 | 11 | 7 | 2021-05-05 22:21 | RED |
| 2021-05-05 22:38 | 11 | 7 | 2021-05-05 22:30 | RED |

And would like to group by Failure_ID/Birth_Time based on ***Time_of_failure*** range that goes from ***Birth_Time*** to ***Birth_Time - 30 minutes*** count the number of each color occurrences

So the expected output for this table would be:

| Birth_Time | ID | COLOR_BLUE | COLOR_YELLOW | COLOR_RED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-05 19:16 | 0 | 2*(19:05/19:12) | 0 *(Because 19:27>19:16) | 0 |
| 2021-05-05 19:38 | 1*(19:12) | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-05-05 20:10 | 2 | 0 | 1*(19:43) | 2*(19:45/19:55) |
| 2021-05-05 22:10 | 11 | 0 | 0 | 2*(22:21/22:30) |

I've attempted to make Birth_Time and ID indexes and then groupby like this:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['ID', "Birth_Time"]), columns=['COLOR']).\
groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(freq="30 Min", label='left', level=1)]).sum()
```

But besides the value count, I still can't manage to set the date range grouping.

Comment: Please share the code that make this df?

Comment: Should there be no match for `ID=2` ?  And some other values too.  Can you verify the expected output ?

Comment: Why is 19:38  YELLOw classes as 1 and not 0

Comment: @wwnde Because BETWEEN TIME [19:38 | 19:08 (19:38 - 30 min) ] there is one failure [19:27]

Comment: Shouldn't the data be separate for each ID ?  19:38 is of ID 1 while 19:27 is of ID 0

Comment: @SeaBean Sorry, I should have explained better, I basically have 2 IDs on my dataset so I tried to simplify it by posting only one here. So, the grouping should be done with the other column. I'll update the question with more info in a few moments

Comment: You sample data has 3 ID, not one?

Comment: @Quang Hoang I updated the table with better clarification regarding the IDs

Comment: Updated data should also has 19:38 YELLOW equal 0, right ?   Since, Time_of_failure 19:43 is after 19:38, not within the 30 minutes range.   Would you please double check your expected result ?

Comment: @SeaBean no, because there is a failure at 2021-05-05 19:27 that is within the range. Even though it has a different ID, it belongs to the same Failure_ID group. I'm trying to group all failures of the same Failure_ID by ID that also fall within the 30 min datetime range

Comment: Your question is not clear. Have you heard of Rubber duck debugging? Do that and repost the question.

Comment: That failure at 19:27 should belong to birth_Time 19:16, not birth_Time 19:38, right ?  Even though taking account into `FailureID` and `ID`

Comment: @SeaBean but we should only take into consideration the Failures where Time_of_failure falls between birth_Time and birth_Time -30min. Hence why we can't count values that are > birht_time. I'll update the expected result with detailed explanations

Comment: Or you want every birthTime to consider ALL Time_of_failure within the same FailureID, not just within the same row ?

Comment: @SeaBean yes exactly! as long as it's the same failure ID and falls within the date range